# Error code Trying to copy from a source that does not exist

Tags: visual-studio-code, yeoman

As I was following the VS code plugin/extension tutorial here [Your First Extension | Visual Studio Code Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension), I got the following error.

```
> yo code

? What type of extension do you want to create? New Extension (TypeScript)
? What's the name of your extension? HelloWorld
? What's the identifier of your extension? helloworld
? What's the description of your extension?
? Initialize a git repository? Yes
? Bundle the source code with webpack? No
? Which package manager to use? npm

Writing in C:\pg\vscode\helloworld...
Error code

Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\generator-code\generators\app\templates\ext-command-ts/vscode
```

Simply the command I ran is, as the tutorial,

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
yo code
```

I'm on Windows 10 elevated Powershell. What's wrong with the error and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context "Nodist", I assume you have installed Nodist on your machine aside from the node.js instance. I'm not sure how you installed your node.js, but it looks the cause of the problem is because the conflict from your node.js and Nodist.

Maybe you can try uninstalling Nodist and try again, or try the same command on a different machine or on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this simply by choosing NOT to initialise a git repository.

Answer (score 1):

For me, uninstalling NodeJS/Nodist and reinstalling in a directory without spaces in the name fixed this. Definitely a classic Windows problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hade a similar error.

I could fix it by simply adding the file .gitignore within the folder.

```
C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-code\generators\app\templates\ext-snippets\.gitignore
```

Comment: @AdrianMole I fixed my answer. It should be more clear now.