# Yeoman for VS Code extension says: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist

Tags: vscode-extensions, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to kickstart a simple VS Code extension using Yeoman, on Windows 10 Pro.

I am facing the same kind of problem that is described here "[Error code Trying to copy from a source that does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67613318/error-code-trying-to-copy-from-a-source-that-does-not-exist)",
however, my configuration is totally different (everything portable) and I suspect that even though the symptoms are the same, my problem has a completely different origin.

I am launching my Yeoman command from Cmder, which is a portable console emulator (https://cmder.net/) that already comes with Git in it.

In Cmder I first installed Yeoman and the VS Code Extension Generator,
and this is what I got:

```
D:\Progs\Cmder (portable)
λ npm install -g yo generator-code
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

added 898 packages, and audited 899 packages in 1m

64 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

7 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 2 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.9.0 -> 8.10.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.10.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.10.0 to update!
npm notice
```

Then I tried to create my project with Yeoman,
and this is what I got:

```
D:\Progs\VS Code (portable)\data\extensions
λ yo code
? ==========================================================================
We're constantly looking for ways to make yo better!
May we anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time?
More info: https://github.com/yeoman/insight & http://yeoman.io
========================================================================== No

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │   Welcome to the Visual  │
    |--(o)--|    │   Studio Code Extension  │
   `---------´   │        generator!        │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /___A___\   /
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

? What type of extension do you want to create? New Extension (JavaScript)
? What's the name of your extension? axel.generique
? What's the identifier of your extension? axel-generique
? What's the description of your extension?
? Enable JavaScript type checking in 'jsconfig.json'? No
? Initialize a git repository? No
? Which package manager to use? npm

Writing in D:\Progs\VS Code (portable)\data\extensions\axel-generique...
Error code

Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: D:\Progs\Node.js (portable)\node_modules\generator-code\generators\app\templates\ext-command-js\vscode
```

It is probably important to mention that I am using a portable version of Node.js (and npm),
located in "D:\Progs\Node.js (portable)", and of course I added this directory to my Path environment variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error message:

> Trying to copy from a source that does not exist:
> C:\Users\dorwi\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.16.0\node_modules\generator-code\generators\app\templates\ext-command-ts\.gitignore

In my case, solved it by just creating an empty .gitignore file in the indicated path

Answer (score 1):

I also use a portable Node version. If you go to the source, there is no .gitignore file there ! You can download the .gitignore file from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-generator-code/tree/main/generators/app/templates/ext-command-ts for example for the Typescript template .